# mysql select max group by id

Tags: mysql

good evening,
i have a table:

```
            A     B     C
           45     1     1
           22     2     1
           40     3     1
           43     1     2
           21     2     2
           61     3     2
           49     4     2
           60     5     2
           76     1     3
           41     2     3
           57     3     3
```

i find `max(A)` from `max(B)` group by `C`. The result should be 60 - max number in `A`  from last row in `B` from each group (`C`)
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly your question you could use an inner join on select `max(b)`:

```
select max(A)
from my_table m
inner  join (
    select C, 
           max(B) act_B
    from my_table  
    group by C
) t on t.act_B =  m.B and t.c = m.c
```